# Optimize MySQL setting for AWS EC2 t2.small

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a web server with `Apache` and `MySQL` running on `AWS EC2 t2.small` with `Windows 2012 Server`. `AWS EC2 t2.small` characteristics:

- RAM 2 GB (used 65%)
- 1 CPU 2.50 GHz (used 1%)

Now MySQL process (`mysqld.exe`) uses 400 MB of RAM (too much for me).

MySQL current settings are (`my.ini`):

```
key_buffer                      = 16M
max_allowed_packet              = 16M
sort_buffer_size                = 512K
net_buffer_length               = 8K
read_buffer_size                = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 8M
tmp-table-size                  = 32M
max-heap-table-size             = 32M
max-connections                 = 500
thread-cache-size               = 50
open-files-limit                = 65535
table-definition-cache          = 1024
table-open-cache                = 2048
query_cache_type                = 1
query_cache_limit               = 256K
query_cache_min_res_unit        = 2k
query_cache_size                = 80M
innodb-log-files-in-group       = 2
innodb-log-file-size            = 64M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit  = 1
innodb-file-per-table           = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 128M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
innodb_log_file_size            = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 50
```

Database is formed by 20 InnoDB tables and they are composed with 5/10 columns. The server has a low traffic.

How can I optimize my settings to be suitable with EC2 t2.small (2GB RAM)?

Answer (score 2):

You have innodb_buffer_pool_size twice in your config. It should be with underscores, but check which one gets used with:

```
show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
```

You could try halving innodb_buffer_pool_size and query_cache_size. Try if performance is ok with query_cache_size=0 too.